# I keep getting "Invalid class typecast" error and I don't know why

Tags: delphi, error-handling, delphi-2010

I am trying to free a component when closing a form but when i run this code I keep getting "Invalid class typecast" error and I don't know why.

```
procedure TfrmMenu.FormHide(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  sID: String;
begin
  I := 0;
  repeat
    Inc(I);
    with dmMenu.qryMcDonalds do
    begin
      SQL.Text := 'Select ItemID FROM tblMenu WHERE ItemID LIKE "' + IntToStr
        (I) + '%"';
      Open;
    end;
    sID := dmMenu.qryMcDonalds.Fields[0].AsString;

    if (Components[I] as TImage).Name = 'imgd' + sID then
    begin (Components[I] as TImage)
      .Free;
    end;

     if (Components[I] as TLabel).Name = 'lbld' + sID then
      begin (Components[I] as TLabel)
      .Free;
      end;
  until I = ComponentCount - 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in this part:

```
    if (Components[I] as TImage).Name = 'imgd' + sID then
    begin (Components[I] as TImage)
      .Free;
    end;

     if (Components[I] as TLabel).Name = 'lbld' + sID then
      begin (Components[I] as TLabel)
      .Free;
      end;
```

An `as` cast in Delphi is basically an assertion cast: you're saying that you're sure it will be that type, and if it's not, to raise an invalid cast exception.  Right now, you're asserting that every single component will be both a `TImage` and a `TLabel`, which obviously will never be true.

What you probably really want to do is this:

```
    if (Components[I] is TImage) and (Components[I].Name = 'imgd' + sID) then
    begin
        Components[I].Free;
    end;

     if (Components[I] is TLabel) and (Components[I].Name = 'lbld' + sID) then
     begin
         Components[I].Free;
      end;
```

You don't actually need the casts in there, since `Name` is [a property on the `TComponent` base class.](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TComponent_Name.html)

**EDIT:** A few points as noted by Andreas in the comments:

First, if you're iterating over a collection and removing items from it, you need to work *backwards.*  To illustrate why, let's remove all even numbers from this list:

`[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]`

So if we do something like this:

```
for i := 0 to list.Length - 1 do
begin
   if list[i] mod 2 = 0 then
   begin
      list.Remove(i);
   end;
end;
```

On the first three iteration, we find numbers that are not even. So far so good.  But on #4, (i = 3), we have an even number.  We remove it from the list.  The list is now `[1, 3, 5, 4, 6]`.  Now we increment `i` to 4.  *Element #4 in this new list is the 6;* we've skipped the 4!  This only works if you're counting backwards, because then deleting things only rearranges the work you've already done, not the work you still have left to do.

Also, the `Components` collection on the form will contain all of your components, in whatever order they were set up in the form designer.  It's not particularly likely that whatever image you called `imgd1` will be component #1 in that collection.  If you're looking for any components of those types with a name starting with `imgd` or `lbld` followed by a number, you'll probably want to write a custom name validation function that checks for that.  But checking if the number is the same as `I` is more or less useless as `I` is completely arbitrary here.

Comment: @okok: Also, you must iterate the component array *backwards* (try to see why!). And you forget to check `Components[0]`. Finally, I think your logic is flawed. You check if the ''n''-th component happens to be named something related to ''n''. You probably need a double-loop solution.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Im not sure I understand

Comment: @okok: Every time you iterate an array to delete elements, you must go from the last element to the first. For instance, say the array contains elements `a[0] = Sarah; a[1] = John; a[2] = Philip` and you iterate the wrong way, from the first to the last element: `for i := 0 to 2 do delete(a, i);` (pseudocode). Then `i` will be `0, 1, 2`, in that order. First, you do `delete(a, 0)`, so you delete `Sarah` and the array becomes `a[0] = John; a[1] = Philip`. Then `i = 1` and you do `delete(a, 1)` and so you delete `Philip`. (Ooops! You forgot to check `John`!). ...

Comment: @okok Updated to address the concerns and questions here.

Comment: (cont.) The array is now `a[0] = John`. Then `i = 2` and you do `delete(a, 2)`. But then the computer (specifically, the Delphi run-time library) will become very upset with you, because `a` is an array of length 1 (index 0 only) and so there is no element with index 2! Now, try to do the same experiment but with a reverse iteration: `2, 1, 0`. Then you'll see it works out. Do you follow, @okok?